# Swapping UIViews in and out of a ViewController's view

Tags: ios, swift, view, storyboard

I'm not entirely new to iOS/Swift development but I've mostly been working on "backend" code so my UI design/development skill level is unfortunately not what I'd like it to be.  With that in mind, I have a UI layout (for a view controller) that looks something like this:

[image]

In this layout, the view labeled "View To Swap" could be in one of three states:

1. It may be hidden (or removed?) in which case StackView B should appear directly below StackView A
2. It may need to show (or be replaced by?) "Subview A"
3. It may need to show (or be replaced by?) "Subview B"

Both Subview A and B will have a button in the upper right hand corner that, when clicked, should remove/hide the "View To Swap" view.

I've been reading about container views a little bit and I'm wondering if this is the approach that I should take here or is there a more simple, direct way to implement this?  I'm currently using the storyboard and autolayout to define my primary view (the view on the left) and constraints but I understand the basics of building a UI programatically if that makes it easier to implement something like this?  Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to insert the 3 main views ( top stack , viewToSwap , bottom stack ) inside a vertical `UIStackView` with `distribution = fillEqually` , and hook `viewToSwap` as `IBOutlet`, whenever you want to hide it do

```
 self.viewToSwap.isHidden = true
```

this will automatically collapse it's content , and you can add any subview to it (A/B) and don't forget `self.viewToSwap.clipsToBounds = true`